# SUM fields in SQL server depending on another field and using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

The title may be a bit vague, but let me explain:

I have a script that creates a database and two tables, one for transactions and one for accounts:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
        transactionID VARCHAR(10),
        description VARCHAR(70),
        accountID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        amount MONEY NOT NULL

        CONSTRAINT transactionsPK
            PRIMARY KEY (transactionID)
)

CREATE TABLE Accounts(
        accountID VARCHAR(10),
        accountName VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
        bank VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL

        CONSTRAINT accountsPK
            PRIMARY KEY (accountID)
)
```

I would like to write a SELECT statement to list all of the fields in the accounts table, along with a total column. I thought I could use an INNER JOIN to only display each account, but I am not sure if DISTINCT would work better.

Its purpose is to SUM all of the transactions for each account, and place that amount in the row for the account itself.

I can achieve the product of listing the amount of each transaction, but not the SUM of all tansactions for each Account.

```
SELECT Accounts.accountID, Accounts.accountName, Accounts.bank, Transactions.amount
    FROM Accounts
    INNER JOIN Transactions
    ON Accounts.accountID = Transactions.accountID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the SUM() function:

```
SELECT a.accountID, a.accountName, a.bank, SUM(t.amount)
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN transactions t
ON a.accountID = t.accountID
GROUP BY a.accountID, a.accountName, a.bank
```

When you are done you need to group by the accountID. This will effectively sum each group (each account).

Here are some SQL [aggregate functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) for you.

Comment: @sgeddes yes I added group by almost immediately after answering I caught my mistake.

Comment: I see that, but you need to `group by` all fields in your `select` clause that are not being used in aggregate functions (`MySql` is the only RDBMS I know of that will work like this).

Comment: @Sgeddes even if accountID is unique? Effectively grouping by those other fields as well?

Comment: Yep, this won't run in most database systems (including `SQL Server`).  `MySQL` allows this syntax, but can produce some random results if it isn't unique.

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks for teaching me something new - edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help :

```
SELECT a.*,
       sumamt
FROM   Accounts a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT accountID,
                               Sum(amount) sumamt
                        FROM   transactions
                        GROUP  BY accountID) AS t
                    ON a.accountID = t.accountID
```

sample sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80420/1)